# Axios Promises map not exiting process

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, axios, es6-promise

I have a list of proxies which I want to test if they are still active or not, after creating a promise list I run through the results, but after the last promise result the process doesnt stop and the programm freezes even though it should finish because there isnt any code after that.

The only fix I found was to put a `process.exit()` after running through all results, but this seems really odd to me. I want to automate the process but because the result function never ends its really difficult to workaround it.

```
const axios = require('axios')
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
const fs = require('fs');

const data = fs.readFileSync("./proxies.txt", "utf-8");
const proxyList = data.split("\n")

const axiosGet = (url, proxy) => {
    const abort = axios.CancelToken.source()
    const id = setTimeout(() => abort.cancel(`Timeout of 60000ms.`), 60000)
    return axios.get(url, { cancelToken: abort.token, httpsAgent: new HttpsProxyAgent(`http://${proxy.trim()}`), proxy: false })
        .then(response => { clearTimeout(id); return true })
        .catch(error => { clearTimeout(id); return false })
}

const promises = proxyList.map((proxy, index) => {
    return axiosGet(`https://api.ipify.org`, proxy, index)
}).map(p => p.catch(e => { e; return false }))


Promise.all(promises)
    .then((results) => {
        results.forEach((result, index) => console.log(index + 1, result))
//not exiting after running through all promises, only process.exit() works
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: How big is proxies.txt? If that's large, you probably need a task queue that adds a limit on how many are being worked on at once.

Comment: Does it work if you try without the `HttpsProxyAgent`?

Comment: @Bergi axios has problems with proxy setup thats why I have to use HttpsProxyAgent I really couldnt find a better alternative

Comment: @ggorlen the proxy.txt file is 10k+ lines but even if I limit it to 10 lines it still freezes edit: it freezes but after sometime it actually ends, maybe its a problem with the timeout not ending?

Comment: @Cryptus I meant: does it still hang if you use plain axios calls without proxying (regardless of the different result)? If no, it's an issue in either the axios or the https-proxy-agent library and should be reported as a bug. (I don't see anything you're doing wrong here, and none of the two libs document that you would have to explicitly shutdown their instances)